# php three regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I spent hours trying to do it and still doesn't work. Even with other topic I can't find the solution.

This is the string :

```
S.C.V. Ch. Latour (Exploitante) Latour Château Latour 33250 PauillacCordonnées GPS : 45.175167 -0.749777Tél: 05 56 73 19 80Fax: 05 56 73 19 81Email: s.favreau@chateau-latour.comSite web: http
```

And I'd like to get three things : the "Tél" number, the "Fax" number and the "Email".

Answer (score 2):

```
/Tél: (.+)Fax: (.+)Email: (.+)Site/
```

There you go. The three submatches are your numbers.

Comment: I dont get how to use your solution

Comment: `preg_match_all('{{your regular expression}}', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

Comment: Note that you must use delimiters. I will add them for clearity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure to have the same order (tél., fax, email, site) for each entry, you can use this:

```
$pattern = '~(?:Tél|Fax|Email): \K([\d ]++|.+?(?=Site web:))~';
```

Comment: Nop it's not working,  `preg_match('~(?:Tél|Fax|Email): \K([\d ]++|.+?(?=Site web:))~', $div->nodeValue, $data);echo 'Tel' . $data[0] . '<br/>';
   echo 'Fax' . $data[1] . '<br/>';`

Comment: @Cédric: normal, you must use preg_match_all, not preg_match

Comment: Its not working neither with preg_match_all, $data[0][0] or $data[1][0] display nothing